# Identify sass mixin location at rails asset precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am updating a ruby on rails app. One of the problem I am encountering is that a sass is no longer compiling because of a missing mixin : `Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'transform'`.

When I am in the non updated app, I can generate the CSS with `rake assets:precompile`. I am trying to understand where the problematic mixin is located when it works.

On a working SASS, is there a way to see where the mixin is defined ?

I want to identify the gem that allow sass to use this mixin.